# Как в jQuery получить свойство padding без px?

Tags: jquery

Получаю свойство `padding-left` так

```
var padding = $(".fixed_block").css("padding-left");
```

Но в переменной пишется значение+px. Как получить только значение, чтобы к нему можно было прибавить число?

Comment: Например: `var padding = parseInt($(".fixed_block").css("padding-left"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведите значение к числу с помощью `parseInt`:

```
var padding = parseInt($(".fixed_block").css("padding-left"));
```

Вы всегда получите значение в пикселях, так как оно всегда возвращается именно в пикселях (даже если исходно было задано в em или как-то еще).

Answer (score 0):

Что бы получить все значения padding, border без значения высоты можно использовать способ с разницей высот:

```
const this_vertical_zise = $(this).outerHeight() - $(this).height();
```

если с margin :

```
const this_vertical_zise = $(this).outerHeight(true) - $(this).height();
```

тоже самое для ширины, только используем метод **.width();**